# Awesomium migration issues (1.7.5) - Client won't start the WebCore

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, awesomium

### The problem:

I just migrated to Awesomium 1.7.5 this week. I'm developing WinForms with Awesomium. Before, I have used 1.7.1 and everything was fine. But after I compiled my new exe with the Awesomium update, the client won't start the WebCore for Awesomium.

I tried everything: giving the client all of the DLL and required files manually, copying the required files with the "copy local" option in Visual Studio 2012, and last but not least I even installed the whole SDK on the client. But it (the client computer) won't start the WebCore, not even once.

So I analyzed the problem, and every time the Awesomium process is not created (webview.isProcessCreated). This is funny, though, because in actuality the Awesomium process is running (see screenshots below).

After testing, I tried to launch the samples from Awesomium. At first I compiled the Visual Studio Examples -> won't start the WebCore. Then I navigated to \Program Files\Awesomium Technologies LLC\Awesomium SDK\1.7.5.0\wrappers\Awesomium.NET\Demos\WinForms and started the Sample.exe -> WebCore doesn't start at all.

I have tested this on x64 and x86 Clients running Windows 7 Enterprise -> no chance.

Even if I reinstall .NET Framework 4.5.1, the WebCore doesn't want to start.

### What it looks like:

With Visual Styles enabled (Windows 7):

[image: Visual Styles enabled]
With Visual Styles disabled (Windows 7):

[image: Without Visual Styles]

So now I don't know how fix that. Do you know a solution, or do I have to fall back to a older version of Awesomium?

### Edit - What debug.log says

> [0104/130436:INFO:(0)] WebCore is now online. [0104/130436:INFO:(0)]
>   Running Awesomium 1.7.5.0

This is very interesting. The Awesomium process has been started, and the debug log says that the WebCore has started and is online.

### Edit - Last working version

I installed all available versions until 1.7.1 separately and tested each version. The last working one is 1.7.4.2.

Comment: have you read about breaking changes? without knowing your code is hard to guess what's the problem

http://wiki.awesomium.net/changelogs/breaking-changes.html